# Obtener nombre de matriz java

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito que al ejecutar el codigo me muestre el nombre de la persona con mejor nota, sin embargo siempre muestra el que esta en el arreglo[0] y la persona con mejor nota. No se como solucionarlo. Alguna idea?

```
    String[] alumnos = {"Diego", "Martina", "Monse", "Gustavo"};

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

        n1 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                n1 = n1 + ((notas[i][j] * 0.15 ) / 4);
                    //luego calculamos el resto de las notas
                n2 = (n1 + (notas[i][4] * 0.20 ) + (notas[i][5] * 0.25) + (notas[i][6] * 0.40));
                    } notas[i][7] = n2;//sacamos la ultima nota que suma el total 

        }for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){

                System.out.print("Notas alumno: " + alumnos[i] + " ");

            for(int j = 0; j < notas.length; j++){

                for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                System.out.print( "[" + notas[i][j] + "]");
                    }    
                System.out.println(String.format(" Nota final --> 
%.1f ",notas[i][7]));
                        suma= notas[0][7] + notas[1][7] + notas[2][7] 
+ notas[3][7];
                }   
       }for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++){
            if(notas[i][7] > mayor){     
               mayor = notas[i][7];
               mejor = i;          
                {
           }      
        }  

    }  int i = 0;
       System.out.println("Mejor: " + alumnos[i]); 
       System.out.print(String.format("  Nota mayor: %.1f ",mayor));     
                System.out.printf(" Promedio general del curso : %.1f " ,promedio,"   ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que encuentres uno mayor al que tienes en las variables, vuelves e imprimes el mensaje. Así, el primero siempre será el mayor... hasta que encuentres otros mayores. Si el de nota 4.6 estuviese último, tendrías tres mensajes y no dos.

Saca la impresión del bucle for. Ahora, iba a modificar tu código pero hay unas llaves puestas tras el primer sysout que no tienen mucho sentido. El punto es que saques

```
System.out.print(String.format("  Nota mayor: %.1f 
",mayor));
```

y lo pongas justo después del cierre del ciclo for que recorre la matriz de alumnos. Junto al mensaje de "Mejor"

De paso, ahora con un fragmento más amplio de código, revisa cómo estás abriendo y cerrando las estructuras de control, pues en el fragmento que revisamos

```
for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++){
            if(notas[i][7] > mayor){     
               mayor = notas[i][7];
               mejor = i;          
                {
           }      
        }
```

Hay una llave de apertura debajo de `mejor = i;` que no tiene por qué estar allí.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, lo coloco fuera del bucle for y sigue el problema, ahi puse mas de codigo

Comment: Edité la respuesta porque se ve algo desordenado el código. Revisa y, si sigue fallando, incluye en la pregunta cualquier error que arroje.